# variables in lisp programming

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function lets say  `A(n)`

which is supposed to have a list

`(the answer is n)`

n being any integer in the list I want when i type  `(A 4)`

it should display  `(the answer is 4)`

I am not sure how to go about it thinking of using `setq and the list function`

But how to construct it its confusing me I'm just a newbie trying to learn lisp, any ideas or books I can read I will greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun A (n) 
  (list 'the 'answer 'is n))
(A 4)
=> (the answer is 4)
```

Comment: Personally I prefer quasiquotes for this: `\`(the answer is ,n)`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young It must be mentioned that in this way fuction can return literal conses.
For example, if code is

    `(,n is what the answer is)

And this can cause non obvious bugs. See [Why does this mapcan cause my REPL to freeze?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207041/why-does-this-mapcan-cause-my-repl-to-freeze)

Comment: @Menschenkindlein Of course, the same caveats apply as when deciding whether to use `list`/`cons` or literals. Since I'm a Schemer, my habit is to return immutable data by default, and only enabling mutability on a case-by-case basis. Certainly I do not mutate objects returned by other functions unless it's expressly documented as being a fresh instance or otherwise okay to mutate.

Answer (score 0):

Another part of your question is what books to read. Usually people recommend to read the "[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)", a book with a friendly and easy-to-read introduction to the Common Lisp. Then there is the "[Getting Started](http://cliki.net/Getting%20Started)" article on Cliki.net. This should be sufficient to get started with the language.