# Why does this mapcan cause my REPL to freeze?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In [this very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194788/768472), it was suggested I could replace this code:

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (apply (function append) (mapcar #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

With this:

```
(defun describe-paths-mapcan (location edges)
  (mapcan #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges))))
```

I certainly understand conceptually why this should work, but it doesn't; the second variation freezes my REPL and the CL prompt never returns. I have to restart SLIME. So I [looked it up](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcan), and am wondering if the fact that mapcan doesn't use `list`, but rather `nconc`, is the cause? Therefore these are actually not identically functioning code blocks?

For the curious, I am passing this:

`(describe-paths-mapcan 'living-room *edges*)`

Where `*edges*` is:

```
(defparameter *edges* '((living-room (garden west door)
             (attic upstairs ladder))
            (garden (living-room east door))
            (attic (living-room downstairs ladder))))
```

And:

```
(defun describe-path (edge)
  `(there is a ,(caddr edge) going ,(cadr edge) from here.))
```

Comment: Is this from _Land of Lisp_?

Comment: @DaoWen initially, but I'm experimenting with other ways to write the examples in that book, so I can learn the language better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it has to do with `describe-edges`. It is defined as:

```
(defun describe-path (edge)
  `(there is a ,(caddr edge) going ,(cadr edge) from here.))
```

The quasiquote there we can `macroexpand`.. And you get:

```
(macroexpand '`(there is a ,(caddr edge) going ,(cadr edge) from here.)) ; ==>
(CONS 'THERE
 (CONS 'IS
  (CONS 'A
   (CONS (CADDR EDGE) (CONS 'GOING (CONS (CADR EDGE) '(FROM HERE.)))))))
```

According to the [documentation for mapcan](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcan) the concatination is done destructively. Looking at the very last element of whats returned from `describe-path` will share structure with the next element it returns so `nconc` will make an infinite loop.

If you were to change `describe-edges` to the following it will work:

```
(defun describe-path (edge)
  (list 'there 'is 'a (caddr edge) 'going (cadr edge) 'from 'here.))
```

Comment: this suggests the quasiquote feature is actually a macro, which i didn't know; hence it's an example of how a macro may be designed in way that prevents other functions of using it properly

Comment: good catch! of course the backquote expander could translate it as `(list 'from 'here.)` too; and how quoted lists behave w.r.t. destructive update is *undefined*, so this really depends on an implementation.

Comment: @WillNess for portable code would it then make sense to avoid use of the backquote and always use `list` instead? at least that way all the behavior is completely defined and predictable

Comment: @OpenLearner yes, either that, or wrap the backquoted form in a `copy-list` call.

Comment: @OpenLearner In the spirit of [LOL](http://landoflisp.com/) I would have avoided mutating functions on arguments since these functions were designed to be functional.

Comment: I don't understand... whether I use `apply` or `mapcan` these functions are essentially the same. What do you mean mutating functions on arguments?

Comment: @OpenLearner Only if the function returns a fresh list. Since `describe-path` didn't the mutation within `describe-paths-mapcan` leaked out and made an infinite loop, something a functional solution wouldn't. So I wouldn't use `mapcan` unless you have performance problems. Try `(progn (setq lst '((1) (2) (3))) (mapcan #'identity lst) lst)`